# Firebase childrenCount

Tags: android, firebase, count, firebase-realtime-database

I know there´s a function of `childrenCount` for a `valueEventListener`, but is there a similar function for `childEventListener` that counts each child before `childAdded` method?

Comment: There is no specific data being passed in to `child_added` for the count of children. Can you give an example of how you would use that?

Comment: I am currently getting markers and set them on a Google Map based on the latitude and longitude of the current user.
When the user moves the map I am querying new markers and because I have previously searched for markers need to close the previous listener if it has added all the markers so that it doesn´t show duplicate markers. So that´s why I need to get the number of markers before querying them, so that the listener closes when all markers have been loaded

Comment: OK. That sounds like a real use-case with actual code where you have a problem. It will be a lot easier to help if you show the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).